Nested-cross validation pipeline and confidence intervals
I'm hoping someone can help me think through this. I've come across a lot of different resources on nested-cv, but I think I'm confused as to how to go about model selection and the appropriate construction of confidence intervals for the training process.
I'm trying to train a binary machine learning classifier. I have a small dataset just over 220 samples, 58 of which have my outcome of interest. Ideally, I'd also like to report a confidence interval on my training to help construct a more reliable estimate of my model performance before evaluating on my held-out test set.
I've currently split my data into training and test sets (80/20) and have been implementing nested-cv validation on the training set. The outer and inner loops have 5 and 3-folds, respectively. My rationale for a nested-cv approach is to ensure that I'm not optimistically biasing my training results using the typical standard 5-fold CV approach when tuning/selecting my model, especially considering my small sample size which I suspect is heavily sensitive to the random splits of my data (the 58 cases are heterogenous among themselves - it's a hard prediction task).
I'm wondering if anyone could comment on whether I'm constructing my Nested-CV pipeline correctly and whether my approach for bootstrapping confidence intervals for estimating the performance of my models is sound? Additionally, my pipeline also performs feature selection, which may cause each of the resulting 'best' models to have used different features. Is it still appropriate to average results and bootstrap confidence intervals?
Currently, my code looks something like this:
Setting up some helper functions
cv_tune = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1839)

scorer = {'AUC': 'roc_auc', 
          'Precision': make_scorer(precision_score, zero_division = 0), 
          'Recall': 'recall',
          'Accuracy': 'accuracy',
          'log-loss': 'neg_log_loss',
          'F1': make_scorer(f1_score, average='binary')}

# this allows us to set a seed
def mutual_info_seed(X, y):
    return mutual_info_classif(X, y, random_state=0)
#SelectKBest(score_func=mutual_info_seed)

# call smote for oversampling
smt = SMOTE(random_state=42)

# Create transformers for each type of feature
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())
])

# Combine transformers into a ColumnTransformer
step_impute_scale = ('scaler', ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, predictors_to_scale)
    ],
    remainder='passthrough'  # this leaves the other columns unchanged
))

# initiate imputer for missing values
simple_imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')

def bootstrap_ci(scores, n_bootstrap=1000, ci=95):
    """Compute bootstrap confidence intervals."""
    bootstrapped_scores = []
    n = len(scores)
    for _ in range(n_bootstrap):
        resample = np.random.choice(scores, size=n, replace=True)
        bootstrapped_scores.append(np.mean(resample))
    lower = np.percentile(bootstrapped_scores, (100 - ci) / 2)
    upper = np.percentile(bootstrapped_scores, 100 - (100 - ci) / 2)
    return np.mean(scores), lower, upper

For running the model
# instantiate rf 
rf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=1725)

# set up pipeline for data pre-processing, feature selection, and smote
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('transform_columns', ColumnTransformer([('imputer', simple_imputer, predictors_to_scale)],
                                                               remainder='passthrough')),
    ('variance_selection', VarianceThreshold()),
    ('selectk', SelectKBest(score_func = mutual_info_seed)),
    ('smote', smt),
    ('classifier', rf)
])

# Define the parameter distributions
param_distributions = {
    'classifier__n_estimators': randint(100, 1001),        # Randomly choose n_estimators between 100 and 1000
    'classifier__max_depth': randint(2, 10),              # Randomly choose max_depth between 2 and 9
    'classifier__min_samples_split': randint(2, 6),       # Randomly choose min_samples_split between 2 and 5
    'classifier__min_samples_leaf': randint(2, 6),        # Randomly choose min_samples_leaf between 2 and 5
    'classifier__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],         # Randomly choose between gini and entropy
    'smote__k_neighbors': randint(1, 10),                  # Randomly choose k_neighbors for SMOTE between 1 and 5
    'selectk__k': randint(5, 15),                          # Randomly choose k for feature selection between 5 and 15
    'variance_selection__threshold': uniform(loc=0, scale=0.3),
}

# Outer cross-validation
outer_cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=1839)

# To store scores for each metric
outer_scores = {metric: [] for metric in scorer.keys()}

# Perform Nested cross-validation
for train_idx, test_idx in outer_cv.split(X_mod, y):
    X_train, X_test = X_mod.iloc[train_idx], X_mod.iloc[test_idx]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_idx], y.iloc[test_idx]
    
    search = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, param_distributions, scoring=scorer, cv=3, n_iter = 250, n_jobs=-1, error_score='raise', 
                           refit = 'F1', random_state=0)
    search.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Evaluate on the outer test set for all metrics
    y_pred = search.predict(X_test)
    y_prob = search.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1] if hasattr(search, "predict_proba") else None

    for metric, scorer_fn in scorer.items():
        if metric == "AUC" and y_prob is not None:
            score = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_prob)
        elif metric == "log-loss" and y_prob is not None:
            score = -log_loss(y_test, y_prob)
        elif callable(scorer_fn):
            score = scorer_fn._score_func(y_test, y_pred)
        else:
            score = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)  # Default fallback
        outer_scores[metric].append(score)

# Compute mean and bootstrap confidence intervals for each metric
results_summary = {}
for metric, scores in outer_scores.items():
    mean_score, ci_lower, ci_upper = bootstrap_ci(scores)
    results_summary[metric] = {
        'mean': mean_score,
        '95% CI': (ci_lower, ci_upper)
    }


Introduction
Training a binary classifier on a small and imbalanced dataset (220 samples, 58 positives) poses some challenges in ensuring robust model evaluation and generalisation. This response will address:

Correctness of your nested CV pipeline.
Appropriateness of bootstrap confidence intervals for performance metrics.
Implications of feature selection within folds.
Additional recommendations for improvement.


1. Correctness of Nested CV Pipeline
Your nested CV setup involves:

Outer CV: 5-fold stratified CV to estimate generalisation.
Inner CV: 3-fold stratified CV for hyperparameter tuning and feature selection.

Why Nested CV?
Nested CV mitigates over-optimism in performance estimation by separating:

Model selection (inner loop) from model evaluation (outer loop).
Feature selection and oversampling (eg., SMOTE) from test set predictions, though see the links further below regarding class imbalance.

This ensures:

No data leakage.
Evaluation reflects the model's performance on truly unseen data.

Mathematical Framework
Nested CV performance can be formalised as:
$$
\text{Performance} = \frac{1}{K} \sum_{k=1}^{K} \text{Metric}(y_{\text{test}, k}, f_{\text{train}, k}(x_{\text{test}, k}))
$$
where:

$K$: Number of outer folds.
$y_{\text{test}, k}$: True outcomes for fold $k$.
$f_{\text{train}, k}$: Model trained on the $k$th training set.

Assessment
Your nested CV pipeline is well-structured:

Stratified Splits: Maintains class balance in folds.
Pipeline Integration: Includes preprocessing, feature selection, and SMOTE.
Reproducibility: Fixed seeds ensure replicability.


2. Confidence Intervals via Bootstrapping
Bootstrapping is appropriate for estimating variability of metrics like $AUC$, $F1$, etc., by resampling outer CV scores. Your implementation:

Resamples with replacement from the outer fold scores.
Computes mean and percentile-based confidence intervals (CIs).

Limitations

Small Sample Bias: With only five outer folds, the resampling process might underestimate variability.
Normality Assumptions: The scores may not follow a normal distribution, affecting CI reliability.

Recommendations

T-distribution CIs: For small samples, compute:
$$
CI = \bar{x} \pm t_{n-1} \cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
where:

$\bar{x}$: Mean score.
$t_{n-1}$: Critical value from the t-distribution.
$s$: Standard deviation of scores.
$n$: Number of folds.


Repeat Nested CV: Run the entire pipeline with different random seeds to assess variability.



3. Implications of Feature Selection Across Folds
Feature selection in the inner loop ensures no data leakage but may result in different features across folds. This can:

Reduce interpretability if the "best" model changes features.
Challenge stability when generalising to new data.

Recommendations

Feature Stability Analysis: Report selection frequencies across folds. Features consistently selected (eg., >70% frequency) are more reliable.
Alternative Methods: Use permutation importance or SHAP values for feature relevance independent of splits.

Averaging Results:

It is appropriate to average performance metrics across folds, as the focus is on predictive performance rather than fixed feature sets. However, provide context on feature variability when interpreting results.


4. Recommendations for Pipeline Improvement
a. Class Imbalance
SMOTE mitigates class imbalance, but alternative methods include:

Balanced Random Forest: Adjusts sampling within trees.
Cost-sensitive Loss Functions: Penalise misclassification of the minority class.
However, I would like to point out that the "class imbalance problem" is not at all the big problem that it is sometimes made out to be. See the following two threads over at Cross Validated:

What is the root cause of the class imbalance problem?
When is unbalanced data really a problem in Machine Learning?
b. Hyperparameter Tuning
Your use of RandomizedSearchCV is efficient. For small datasets, consider:

Bayesian Optimisation: Smarter hyperparameter search (eg., Optuna).

c. Robustness Testing
Repeat the nested CV process with different random seeds to assess performance consistency. Compare metrics across iterations to validate robustness.
d. Metric Selection
Focus on metrics suited for imbalanced datasets:

Precision-Recall AUC: Provides a more nuanced evaluation than ROC AUC.


5. Results Reporting
Example Table



Metric
Mean Score
95% CI (Bootstrap)




AUC
0.85
(0.81, 0.89)


Precision
0.75
(0.71, 0.79)


Recall
0.68
(0.64, 0.72)


F1 Score
0.71
(0.68, 0.74)


Accuracy
0.80
(0.77, 0.83)



Interpretation:

Include the number of outer folds ($n=5$) and repetitions for context.
Link performance metrics back to business objectives or research questions.


Conclusion
Your implementation demonstrates a good approach to model evaluation. Addressing feature stability, exploring alternative class imbalance methods (though please do read the two links I gave above), and repeating the process for robustness will enhance the reliability of the results. Confidence intervals provide valuable context, but be cautious of their limitations with small datasets.

Thank you. Robert. Just to clarify, when you state: "Normality Assumptions: The scores may not follow a normal distribution, affecting CI reliability." -- isn't that the benefit of bootstrapping since it doesn't assume a normal distribution? I would think this would be the preferred method of conducting CIs over the T-distribution CIs as described?

@molecularrunner You're right that it does not assume a normal distribution for the underlying data. However, the reliability of bootstrapped confidence intervals depends on having sufficient variability in the data, which is a challenge with only five outer CV folds.

Right-and I suppose that the T-distribution CIs would run into the same problem, since I only have 5 data points. Is repeated Nested CV the better option? Say nested CV 10x with different data splits, giving me 50 outer validation scores to bootstrap from? After I perform nested CV to estimate the generalizability of the model, I could then retrain the model using 5-fold CV on all my training data to identify best hyperparameters and then apply that model to my heldout test set? It seems to me that nested CV is more to derive a reliable estimate of performance, rather than for training a model

You’re correct: t-distribution CIs also struggle with only 5 points. Repeated nested CV (eg., 10x5 outer folds) is indeed a better option, providing more variability for bootstrapping. This should provide more reliable performance estimates. Afterward, retraining on all training data using 5-fold CV for hyperparameter tuning before applying to the test set is also sound. Nested CV focuses on performance estimation, not final training, so your ideas make sense to me, and meets with best practices. However, I advise caution with repeated nested CV to avoid overfitting if tuning is "aggressive".
